# Adding delay in sending SMS in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, sms

I am developing an application that sends SMS to the selected contacts at regular intervals for a specified number of times. I have the SMS-sending functionality working, but I need to add a delay between sending SMS after each round.

For example, if I want a message M to be sent to S and D in my contacts, I need the app to wait for N seconds before sending the same message again to S and D.

How can I get this working? How do I add the delay function between sending the messages to the contacts?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

simply said, you can't.
It's not allowed to send messages yourself, you can only pop-up the sms-displayer and the user himself has to tap 'send'.
So if doing it programmatically in an app, this is not possible.
It might be possible if you're sending text messages using a server or something..

Answer (score 1):

Would it be possible to set a NSTimer to go of for a certain number of times at certain intervals and have your app run in the background after it has been closed?

Make a timer:

```
int N = 3;

_myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:N target:self selector:@selector(myMethod) userInfo:myContact repeats:YES];


-(void)myMethod:(NSTimer*)timer {
    // Now I can access all the properties and methods of myObject
    [[timer userInfo] myObjectMethod];
}
```

Running in the background I am not as familiar with however if you start looking for beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: Im sure you will find the answers that you need.

Hope this helps, Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have SMS sending functionality figured out then all you need is:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(sendSMS) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0];
```

This is if your SMS data is somewhere in the `model`. If you need to send some data to your `sendSMS` method then use:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(sendSMS:) withObject:objectData afterDelay:5.0];
```

Comment: Although not stated explicitly, I think the question relates to sending an SMS programatically and without any user intervention. This would still require someone to tap "send"

Comment: Hmm, why would this require someone to tap "send"? By sendSMS method i ment method that OP already has for sending SMS.

Comment: Because the method they already have for sending SMS requires that you tap "send". You can't send an SMS without the user tapping "send" (unless you do it from your server)